# Un-grouping in Powershell

Tags: powershell, grouping, rows

I am using the following to get a list of AD Sites and Subnets, however it is currently grouping multiple subnets at each site into one row. I would like a row for each subnet, with the SiteName and AD Controller as well.

```
$Sites = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest().Sites

$AllSites = @()

foreach ($Site in $Sites) {
  $obj = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property (
    @{
      "SiteName"  = $site.Name;
      "SubNets" = $site.Subnets;
      "Servers" = $Site.Servers
    }
  )

  $AllSites += $obj       
}

$AllSites | Out-GridView
```

I know how to use the `Group-Object` cmdlet and naively assumed there might be an un-group cmdlet, but I have been unable to find one or any information relating to un-grouping in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand the `Group` property of grouped objects to ungroup them:

```
... | Select-Object -Expand Group
```

However, I suspect that you don't actually want to ungroup grouped objects, but expand your server and subnet lists to string representations. Assuming that they're arrays of strings you'd simply join those arrays like this:

```
$AllSites = foreach ($Site in $Sites) {
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    'SiteName' = $Site.Name
    'SubNets'  = $Site.Subnets -join ','
    'Servers'  = $Site.Servers -join ','
  }
}
```

To get one line per subnet you'd loop over the subnets inside the outer loop:

```
$AllSites = foreach ($Site in $Sites) {
  $Site.Subnets | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
      'SiteName' = $Site.Name
      'SubNet'   = $_
      'Servers'  = $Site.Servers -join ','
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The first selection "select-object -expand Group" was exactly what I needed. Many thanks @Ansgar Wiechers

Answer (score 0):

You can use Select-Object-ExpandProperty to expand a single property; though, that wont give you one row per subnet.  For that you'll need to build a second for loop to go over each subnet and build a new object:

```
foreach ($Site in $Sites) {
  foreach($subnet in $Site.Subnets) {
    $obj = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{            
      "SiteName"  = $site.Name;            
      "SubNets" = $subnet;            
      "Servers" = $Site.Servers            
    }              
    $AllSites += $obj
  }
}
```